# Using the LIKE condition in a query in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to find out if a similar record already exists in the DB before I go ahead and save a record. I've googled and found what looks like it should work but unfortunately doesn't. I'm new to cakephp and can' figure out the correct query.

```
$this->Tape->recursive = -1;
$tapeexists = $this->Tape->find('all', array('condition'=>array('Tape.name LIKE'=>'blondie%')));
$this->set('output', $tapeexists);
```

If I print_r() the results in the view I can see that it just goes and gets all the results in that table, none of which have a name anything even remotely like 'blondie'!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you simply misspelled `conditions` when doing your find:

```
$tapeexists = $this->Tape->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Tape.name LIKE'=>'blondie%')));
```

That should give you the expected results.

For your particular goal of not allowing duplicates, I would recommend creating a validation rule on the `Tape` model. There is a specific built-in rule designed to avoid duplicates, so you'd probably be better off using it. Check out more information about data validation [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html) - check out the `isUnique` core validation rule.

Comment: Oh dear. Feel wick. That was really annoying me, I'll have to learn to be more careful. Thanks for the suggestion about the validation rule too. Good idea!

Comment: No worries, we were all beginners once :) Can you please mark the answer as accepted so I get some reputation? Thank you!

Comment: I tried this with 'name LIKE', but the validator seems to delete this and fails with unknown column `nameLIKE`

Answer (score 0):

i had the same question and bumped into an error.

"String could not be converted to Integer"

I did exactly as in the [cookbook4](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-count-of-results) descriped to do a query "LIKE %%" but failed. (The $search variable contains an integer, i double checked!)

I got it to worked in CakePhP 4.3.11 like this:

```
$query = $this->Orders->find('all', [
            'conditions' => ['order_number LIKE "%' . $search . '%"']
        ]);
```

I did not user 'column' => '%value%' since this always failed.

Hope this helps others that stumble upon the same problem